# How to draw on a zoomed image?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I have a picturebox of `Size` 400X400 in my application. The `SizeMode` of the picturebox is set to `Zoomed`. I have loaded a png image of 700X446 in the picturebox.

[image]

I have following issue,

Even though I am drawing a black straight line along the red path, actually it is being shown along the loaded image out of perspective.

How can I solve the issue?

**P.S.** I want to draw only on the image, not the entire picturebox.

**Source Code:**

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
    Bitmap _inputImage = null;
    //Graphics _imageGraphics = null;

    #region ctor
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _inputImage = Bitmap.FromFile(@"E:\cracked.png") as Bitmap;

        this.inputImagePictureBox.Image = _inputImage;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Mouse Up and Down
    Point _startPoint = Point.Empty;

    private void left_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _startPoint = e.Location;

            Circle tempCircle = new Circle(_startPoint, 10);

            Bitmap tempImage = (Bitmap)_inputImage.Clone();

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);

            tempCircle.Draw(g);

            inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
        }
    }

    private void pressed_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (_startPoint != e.Location)
            {
                Line tempLine = new Line(_startPoint, e.Location);

                Bitmap tempImage = (Bitmap)_inputImage.Clone();

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);

                tempLine.Draw(g);

                inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
            }
        }
    }

    Bitmap _savedImage;

    private void left__MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (_startPoint != e.Location)
            {
                Line tempLine = new Line(_startPoint, e.Location);

                Bitmap tempImage = (Bitmap)_inputImage.Clone();

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);

                tempLine.Draw(g);

                _savedImage = tempImage;

                inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
            }
            else
            {
                Bitmap tempImage = (Bitmap)_inputImage.Clone();
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);

                inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can restrict the clipping area and scale the graphics object..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to address two issues:

- **Clip** the `Graphics` area to the actual `Image` instead of the whole `PictureBox.ClientArea`
- **Scale** the coordinates of the mouse events to the actual image when receiving and recording them and back again when you use them to draw in the `Paint` event.

For both we need to know the **zoom** factor of the `Image`; for the clipping we also need to know the `ImageArea` and for drawing I simply store two mouse locations.

Here are the class level variable I use:

```
PointF mDown = Point.Empty;
PointF mLast = Point.Empty;
float zoom = 1f;
RectangleF ImgArea = RectangleF.Empty;
```

Note that I use `floats` for all, since we will need to do some dividing..

First we'll calculate the `zoom` and the `ImageArea`:

```
void GetImageScaleData(PictureBox pbox)
{
    SizeF sp = pbox.ClientSize;
    SizeF si = pbox.Image.Size;
    float rp = 1f * sp.Width / sp.Height;   // calculate the ratios of
    float ri = 1f * si.Width / si.Height;   // pbox and image

    if (rp > ri)
    {
        zoom = sp.Height / si.Height;
        float width = si.Width * zoom;
        float left = (sp.Width - width) / 2;
        ImgArea = new RectangleF(left, 0, width, sp.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        zoom = sp.Width / si.Width;
        float height = si.Height * zoom;
        float top = (sp.Height - height) / 2;
        ImgArea = new RectangleF(0, top, sp.Width, height);
    }
}
```

This routine should be called each time a new `Image` is loaded and also upon any **Resizing** of the `PictureBox`:

```
private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetImageScaleData(pictureBox1);
}
```

Now ne need store the mouse locations. Since they must be **reusable after a resize** we need to tranfsorm them to image coordinates. This routine can do that and also back again:

```
PointF scalePoint(PointF pt, bool scale)
{
    return scale ? new PointF( (pt.X - ImgArea.X) / zoom, (pt.Y - ImgArea.Y) / zoom)
                 : new PointF( pt.X * zoom + ImgArea.X, pt.Y * zoom + ImgArea.Y);
}
```

Finally we can code the `Paint` event

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Fuchsia, 2.5f) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot})
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, Rectangle.Round(ImgArea));

    e.Graphics.SetClip(ImgArea);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, scalePoint(mDown, false), scalePoint(mLast, false));
}
```

.. and the mouse events:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = scalePoint(e.Location, true);
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mLast = scalePoint(e.Location, true);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

[image]

For more complex drawing you would store the coordinates in `List<PointF>` and transform them back, pretty much like above..:

```
List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
```

and then:

```
e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Pens.Orange, points.Select(x => scalePoint(x, false)).ToArray());
```