# How to return clear image

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

For example, im load big images (11000x8000) in `PictureBox` and then draw lines and etc. on it.

How to return clear image **WITHOUT RELOAD** from hadrdrive or memory. I thing there picturebox or graphics alternative who can this.
Now im use temp bitmap for clean image

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(TempBitmap);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
Point gPoint = Utils.GameToPoint(p, Image.Width, Image.Height, 2);
g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), gPoint.X - 5, gPoint.Y + 5, gPoint.X + 5, gPoint.Y - 5);
g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), gPoint.X - 5, gPoint.Y - 5, gPoint.X + 5, gPoint.Y + 5);
Image = bitmap;
base.CenterAt(gPoint);
```

Comment: How do you draw? Into the image or onto the control? Show some code!

Comment: What do you mean with 'clear image'? Filling it with a solid color?

Comment: Clean image = iamge without my graphics changes. Add paint example

Comment: If you draw into the bitmap, as your code shows, then you either have to load it from disk or cache a copy. The alternative would be to draw onto the picturebox's surface in the Paint event, using the e.Graphics object. There the Image remains clean and all you need to do is set a flag or clear your data and call Invalidate.

Comment: Im try to override OnPaint, but imagebox have scroll and zoom, and it is not considered for this. Drawn does not move along with the image

Comment: You can/need to scale and/or  translate the Graphics object as you scale the Image. Resource-friendly but takes  a bit of  coding.. [See here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303881/how-to-draw-on-a-zoomed-image/39305038?s=1|1.8337#39305038) And [here is another one](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+draw+zoom)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to undo changes you made to your picture. You only have two possibilities:

1. Reload the picture (what you don't want)
2. Make your own control (inherited from picturebox) and override the `OnPaint` method. That method will be called on every refresh. First call `base.OnPaint`, then draw all your stuff. But this draw calls have to be repeated on every refresh.