# C# Get Color of Picturebox with the mouse (Almost complete)

Tags: c#

My code is almost done but it doesnt work. It gives me the wrong location of the image and I **think it's because the image is set to Streched.**

Any help?

```
        private void originalmaster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var rato = e as MouseEventArgs;
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(originalmaster.Image);
        Color c = b.GetPixel(rato.X, rato.Y);
        h = Math.Round(c.GetHue(), 0);
        h = (h * 255) / 360;
        s = Math.Round(c.GetSaturation() * 255, 0);
        v = Math.Round(c.GetBrightness() * 255, 0);


        lb_valores_hsv.Text = "H: " + h + " S: " + s + " V: " + v;
        lb_valores_rgb.Text = "R: " + c.R + " G: " + c.G + " B: " + c.B;

    }
```

The location of rato is incorrect.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose that bitmap

Comment: I've never seen someone convert a Click's EventArgs to a MouseEventArgs before.  Why not just use the MouseDown event?

Comment: what do you mean cast the image to bitmap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer:

```
     MouseEventArgs rato = e as MouseEventArgs;
     Bitmap b = ((Bitmap)originalmaster.Image);
     int x = rato.X * b.Width / originalmaster.ClientSize.Width;
     int y = rato.Y * b.Height / originalmaster.ClientSize.Height;
     Color c = b.GetPixel(x, y);
```

Comment: I got the surprising cast (`MouseEventArgs`) from the question. Surprised me too.

Comment: what's the point of using cast instead of creating a new bitmap?

Comment: @TiagoSilva It's much simpler not to create a whole new bitmap. It saves memory and time. This assumes that originalmaster is already a bitmap and not a Windows Metafile (WMF) or something incompatible with Bitmap.

Answer (score 3):

First you need a function to convert the mouse position to the same stretching/zooming as the Image:

```
PointF stretched(Point p0, PictureBox pb)
{
    if (pb.Image == null) return PointF.Empty;

    float scaleX = 1f * pb.Image.Width  / pb.ClientSize.Width;
    float scaleY = 1f * pb.Image.Height / pb.ClientSize.Height;

    return new PointF(p0.X * scaleX, p0.Y * scaleY);
}
```

Then you can use it to retrive pixel data from the clicked position:

```
private void originalmaster_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mDown = Point.Round(stretched(e.Location, originalmaster));
    Color c = ((Bitmap)originalmaster.Image).GetPixel(mDown.X, mDown.Y);
    // do your stuff:
    BackColor = c;

}
```

Notes:

- No need to create a new `Bitmap`; simply casting the `Image` to `Bitmap` will do
- Note that the function returns `PointF` for better precision..
- ..but as we don't need it here I cast back to `Point`
- `MouseClick` (or `MouseDown`) is the better event as it contains mouse info without casting the `e` parameter
- The code assumes the `PictureBox` is **not** in `ViewMode CenterImage`. For this case, where the `Image` usually doesn't start at the top left corner, you need a more involved function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303881/how-to-draw-on-a-zoomed-image/39305038?s=2|0.0834#39305038) for an example of calculation the actual image area..

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It will just get the color of the pixel under the cursor.

If there is no picture it will just return the default colour of the control.

Note: I have written this for mouse move, but the same logic applies on click.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int dwRop);


        public Color GetColorAt(Point location)
        {
            using (Bitmap screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
            {
                using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
                {
                    using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle))
                    {
                        IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
                        IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
                        int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, hSrcDC, location.X, location.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                        gdest.ReleaseHdc();
                        gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
                    }
                }

                return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
            }
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.BackColor = GetColorAt(e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks really really complicated.

Comment: Thats just because I have included all of the code, its far less complicated than having to work out the ratio of cursor position and image size. it just gets the pixel under the cursor. its doesnt matter what the image is like inside, or even if there is an image at all.

Comment: Hm, makes some sense. But I still do not think it is a good idea, if only because it probably depends on the display colors instead of the Bitmap content, doesn't it? And two divisions in a user action are neither complicated nor any other problem at all. Still an interesting approach.

Comment: I have retracted my downvote but still wouldn't touch the solution unless I saw some good reason..

Comment: Thanks,  - who knows, perhaps the OP would want to extend it to get the pixel colour of anywhere on the desktop :)