# Draw Rectangle inside picture box SizeMode Zoom

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, picturebox

I have a picture box in a WindowsForms project with its SizeMode to "Zoom".

I want to draw a rectangle inside image and get its coordinates relative to the image and not to the picture box.

**The problem is that the rectangle's coordinates do not match with the same rectangle selected on Windows Paint Application.**

Here is the code used:

1. Start Painting:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Starts drawing.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="sender"></param>
   /// <param name="e"></param>
   private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       backupImage = pictureBox1.Image;
       _once = true;
       RectStartPoint = e.Location;
       pictureBox1.Invalidate();
   }
   ```
2. While moving mouse:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// While moving mouse event, paint rectangle
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="sender"></param>
   /// <param name="e"></param>
   private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_once) //Only draw rectangle while drawing mode
       {
           Point tempEndPoint = e.Location;
           Rect.Location = new Point(Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, tempEndPoint.X),
               Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, tempEndPoint.Y));

           Rect = new Rectangle(
               Math.Min(tempEndPoint.X, Rect.Left),
               Math.Min(tempEndPoint.Y, Rect.Top),
               Math.Min(e.X - RectStartPoint.X, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width - RectStartPoint.X),
               Math.Min(e.Y - RectStartPoint.Y, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height - RectStartPoint.Y));

           pictureBox1.Refresh();
           pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(cropPen, Rect);
       }
   }
   ```
3. When 2 click, finhish painting rectange:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// When mouse click is released, write in texbox the rectangle's coordinates.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="sender"></param>
   /// <param name="e"></param>
   private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_once)
       {
           if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
           {
               Point tempEndPoint = e.Location;

               _once = false;
               string sAux = string.Format("Left: {0}; Top: {1}; Width: {2}; Height: {3} \r\n", Math.Min(tempEndPoint.X, Rect.Left), Math.Min(tempEndPoint.Y, Rect.Top),
                       Math.Min(e.X - RectStartPoint.X, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width - RectStartPoint.X), Math.Min(e.Y - RectStartPoint.Y, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height - RectStartPoint.Y));

               textBox1.Text += sAux;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The results are:

Windows Image
[image: Windows Image]

Paint Image
[image]

As you can see on both images, left, top, width and height do not match.

Can you tell me how to obtain the same result?

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2swJ9.jpg)

Comment: You need to calculate the zoom and then apply it to the rectangle. `float zoom =  1f * PBox.Image.Width / PBox.ClientSize.Width`

Comment: Hi TaW, thank you for your answer. It does not work because when I start drawing the rectangle, the coordinates are relative to the picturebox instead of the image, so to maintain aspect ratio, in this case, the height of the picturebox is bigger than the image height.

Comment: Not sure how that matters. Note that if you have emtpy areas (do you?), ie if the ratios of image and pbox are not the same you need to calculate and use the imageareas as shown in one of the links. Then scale all numbers of the rectangle. - To check we would need to know the ClientSize of the PBox.

Comment: I edited my first post to add another example image. In this case, I retrieve this values: Left: 5; Top: 38; Width: 870; Height: 196. As you can see the top line of the rectangle is locate above the image start (0,0).

Comment: Did you calculate the ImgArea from the SetImageScale function in the link? It should be the base for the calculations..

Comment: This question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303881/how-to-draw-on-a-zoomed-image/39305038?s=2|20.4150#39305038)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function to help with various calculations:

```
void SetImageScale(PictureBox pbox, out RectangleF ImgArea, out float zoom)
{
    SizeF sp = pbox.ClientSize;
    SizeF si = pbox.Image.Size;
    float rp = sp.Width / sp.Height;   // calculate the ratios of
    float ri = si.Width / si.Height;   // pbox and image

    if (rp > ri)
    {
        zoom = 1f * sp.Height / si.Height;
        float width = si.Width * zoom;
        float left = (sp.Width - width) / 2;
        ImgArea = new RectangleF(left, 0, width, sp.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        zoom = 1f * sp.Width / si.Width;
        float height = si.Height * zoom;
        float top = (sp.Height - height) / 2;
        ImgArea = new RectangleF(0, top, sp.Width, height);
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use it, given a `Rectangle Rect` which you created from the mouse coordinates:

```
float zoom = 1f;
RectangleF ImgArea = Rectangle.Empty;

SetImageScale(pictureBox1, out ImgArea, out zoom);

Point RLoc = Point.Round(new PointF( (Rect.X - ImgArea.X) / zoom, 
                                     (Rect.Y - ImgArea.Y) / zoom ));
Size RSz = Size.Round(new SizeF(Rect.Width / zoom, Rect.Height / zoom));

label1.Text =  "Selection in mouse coordinates: "  + Rect.ToString();
label2.Text =  "Selection in image coordinates: "  + new Rectangle(RLoc, RSz).ToString();
```

This should work no matter whether the images are landscape or portrait or which ratio if any is greater, the Image's or the PictureBox's.

[image]

Note that with the images strongly zoomed it is hard to do a pixel-pefect selection..

The function is variant of the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303881/how-to-draw-on-a-zoomed-image).