# How to measure length of line which is drawn on image? C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to write an application that will measure fragments of a specimen examined under a microscope. I thought that the best way would be to capture the image and draw on selected parts of the specimen then count the value of the drawn line in pixels (and later to convert this value into the appropriate unit).

Is there anything that helps solve such issue already implemented or any tool/package or something that allows such calculations?

I will also willingly learn about solutions in other programming languages if they allow to solve this problem in a easier way or just in some way.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! Winforms: Display in PictureBox and code Mouse events: Down,Move and Up. Just a few lines to get at the pixels..

Comment: From start- and endpoint you can calculate the distance in pixels. But converting that to millimeters (or whatever length-unit you want) is a challenge!

Comment: I would suggest looking at OpenCV. It's a C++ Computer Vision library that also has Python bindings (I'd suggest Python over C++ if you're coming from C#). I believe it provides a Line Segment Detector as part of it's API. If you are willing to make an interactive application you could avoid CV and just capture the start and end position of the line segment from mouse clicks. Then use the distance formula multiplied by whatever scale you choose to convert from pixels to real units.

Comment: The 'challenge' is to know the zoom factors if the image is displayed zoomed and to trust the dpi values.

Comment: If you know the start and end points, you can use the Delta-x and Delta-y in the Pythagorean theorem to determine length.

Comment: Unit conversion is not a problem. I know exactly how to do it. The problem is the shape of the examined fragments of the object. Lines are curved, sometimes wavy or even round. I know how to count the distances of straight lines or from point to point. The problem is to calculate the length of non-standard shapes. Capturing the start and end position of the line segment from mouse clicks looks like a really good idea so if someone could help to develop this idea i would be grateful.

Comment: Curved lines are nor that easy to place but clicking often enough should be good enough. The result of collecting each in the MouseDown event is a List<Point> which you can display with Grahhics.DrawLines in a Paint event in winforms. The length is then simply the sum of the respective segments. To show you an example we need to know what are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..

Comment: The best solution for me would be WPF but as I said I can adjust if you see a better solution using a different platform.

Comment: I don't do WPF; if you want I can show you a Winforms example using <40 lines.. Anyone knowledgeable in WPF will surely be able to do something similar there.

Comment: Of course i want. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have added a few corrections as well as zooming code to allow better precision :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic example of measuring a segmented line drawn onto an  image in winforms.

It uses a `PictureBox` to display the image, a `Label` to display the current result and for good measure I added two `Buttons` the clear all points and to undo/remove the last one.

I collect to pixel positions in a `List<Point>` :

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
```

The two edit buttons are rather simple:

```
private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    points.Clear();
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    show_Length();
}

private void btn_Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (points.Any())points.Remove(points.Last());
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    show_Length();
}
```

Note how I trigger the `Paint` event by invalidating the image whenever the points collection changes..

The rest of the code is also simple; I call a function to calculate and display the sum of all segment lengths. Note that I need at least **two** points before I can do that or display the first line..

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    points.Add(e.Location);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    show_Length();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (points.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, points.ToArray());
}

void show_Length()
{
    lbl_len.Text = (pointsF.Count) + " point(s), no segments. " ;

    if (!(points.Count > 1)) return;

    double len = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        len += Math.Sqrt((points[i-1].X - points[i].X) * (points[i-1].X - points[i].X) 
                    +  (points[i-1].Y - points[i].Y) * (points[i-1].Y - points[i].Y));
    }
    lbl_len.Text = (points.Count-1) + " segments, " + (int) len + " pixels";
}
```

A few notes:

- The image is displayed without any zooming. `PictureBox` has a `SizeMode` property to make zoomed display simple. In such a case I recommend to store not the direct pixel locations of the mouse but 'unzoomed' values and to use a 'rezoomed' list of values for the display. This way you can zoom in and out and still have the points stick to the right spots.
- For this you ought to use a `List<PointF>` to keep precision.
- When zooming e.g. by enlarging the `PictureBox`, maybe after nesting it in a `Panel`, make sure to either keep the aspect ratio equal to that of the `Image` or to do a [full calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316403/draw-rectangle-inside-picture-box-sizemode-zoom/50326689#50326689) to include the extra space left or top; in `SizeMode.Normal` the  image will always sit flush *TopLeft* but in other modes it will not always do so.
- For the calculation of actual i.e. physical distances simply divide by the actual dpi value.

Let's see what we have in action:

[image]

**Update:**

To get a chance to create cloers fits and better precision we obviously need to zoom in on the image.

Here are the necessary changes:

We add a list of 'floating  points':

```
List<PointF> pointsF = new List<PointF>();
```

And use it to store the un-zoomed mouse positions in the mouse down:

```
pointsF.Add( scaled( e.Location, false));
```

We replace all other occurances of `points` with `pointsF`.

The `Paint` event always calculates the scaled points to the current zoom level:

```
if (pointsF.Count > 1)
{
    points = pointsF.Select(x => Point.Round(scaled(x, true))).ToList();
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, points.ToArray());
}
```

And the function to do the scaling looks like this:

```
PointF scaled(PointF p, bool scaled)
{
    float z = scaled ? 1f * zoom : 1f / zoom;
    return new PointF(p.X * z, p.Y * z);
}
```

It uses a class level variable `float zoom = 1f;` which gets set along with the picturebox's `Clientsize` in the `Scroll` event of a trackbar:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<float> zooms = new List<float>()
    { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1f, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    zoom = zooms[trackBar1.Value];

    int w = (int)(pictureBox2.Image.Width * zoom);
    int h = (int)(pictureBox2.Image.Height * zoom);

    pictureBox2.ClientSize = new Size(w, h);
    lbl_zoom.Text = "zoom: " + (zoom*100).ToString("0.0");
}
```

The picturebox is nested inside a `Panel` with `AutoScroll` on. Now we can zoom and scroll while adding segments:

[image]

Comment: take a note that this is far from perfect if you are doing "science"! It is vastly dependant on operator accuracy.

Comment: Of course. The next step would be to implement zooming in to give him a chance to go beyond display pixel precision..